# What is wrong with my script? It doesn't return a message with the "if statement"

Tags: javascript, html

i've made this script but it won't work properly, what i want is an input box, and if i use it the site returns some text.

```js
function myFunction();
var text_input = document.getElementById("input001").value;
if (text_input == "4") {
  document.getElementById("message001").innerText = "Correct!";
} else {
  document.getElementById("message001").innerText = "nope";
}
}
```

```html
<div class=questions>
  <p>What is 9-5?</p>
</div>

<input id="input001" type="text" />
<button onclick="myFunction()">Check</button>
<p id="message001"></p>
```

Comment: Did You check your console?

Comment: @KrishnaPrashatt Nop, Its just the problem with the semi-colon he used after the function name

Comment: @ThanveerShah, yep noticed it just now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is you are closing your function with a semi colon.

Instead, put an opening parenthesis

```
function myFunction(){
        var text_input=document.getElementById("input001").value;
        if (text_input=="4"){
            document.getElementById("message001").innerText="Correct!";
            }
        else{
            document.getElementById("message001").innerText="nope";
            }
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function myFunction(){//changed line no need to add ; here
var text_input = document.getElementById("input001").value;
 if (text_input == "4") {
   document.getElementById("message001").innerText = "Correct!";
  } else {
   document.getElementById("message001").innerText = "nope";
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have the wrong format for `function` definition

you just need `{` after creating a function for the scope

```
function myFunction(){
   // your code
}
```

```js
function myFunction(){
            var text_input=document.getElementById("input001").value;
            if (text_input=="4"){                                           document.getElementById("message001").innerText="Correct!"
                        
            }
            else{
                document.getElementById("message001").innerText="nope"
                }
            }
```

```html
<!--first question-->
            <div class=questions>
                <p>What is 9-5?</p>
            </div>
    
            <input id="input001" type="text" />
            <button onclick="myFunction()">Check</button>
            <p id="message001"></p>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
function myFunction() {
  var text_input = document.getElementById("input001").value;
  if (text_input == "4") {
    document.getElementById("message001").innerText = "Correct!";
  } else {
    document.getElementById("message001").innerText = "nope";
  }
}
```

```html
<div class=questions>
  <p>What is 9-5?</p>
</div>

<input id="input001" type="text" />
<button onclick="myFunction()">Check</button>
<p id="message001"></p>
```

You have syntax errors. Find This Example, It will work.

Answer (score 0):

Apart from the fact that you declared only a function with an error (notice a semicolon right after function name), your code doesn't work because you are not passing a function in button's `onclick` attribute - you're just passing the return value of that function there. You should have `<button onclick="myFunction">Check</button>` there instead.

Below the correct code:

```js
function myFunction() {
  var text_input = document.getElementById("input001").value;
  if (text_input == "4") {
    document.getElementById("message001").innerText = "Correct!";
  } else {
    document.getElementById("message001").innerText = "nope";
  }
}
```

```html
<div class=questions>
  <p>What is 9-5?</p>
</div>

<input id="input001" type="text" />
<button onclick="myFunction">Check</button>
<p id="message001"></p>
```